# How to add Client-Server to Android app activites

Tags: android, android-studio, server, client, client-server

So I am building a mobile application in Android Studio. The application allows multiple users on different devices can log into their account. One of the features that I would like to implement is a live chat between online users.

I have done this in eclipse, using a Client-Server model over a local network. The server sets up a socket, which is threaded so multiple clients can connect and chat. This works in eclipse using Java swing, which is easy as communicating with the Server and updating the UI is all done in one class.

I am relatively new to Android development however, and am struggling to get this to work where the communication between the Client and Server can be displayed on the UI via the Activity.

Can anyone please explain how you link between an Activity and my Client class please? Below I have put my Server, ServerThreads and Client class, which (over a terminal) can correctly communicate.

Server:

```
package com.degree.abbylaura.demothree.Server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {


 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    //create a server and client sockets
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;

    int portNumber = 8888; //TO BE CHANGED


    //setup server socket
    try{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        System.out.println("Socket set up");

        //in true loop listen forever for incoming connections
        //allows multiple clients to be handled
        while(true) {

            //accept connection with clients socket
            //open reader and writer for communication
            try {

                //connection accepted
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("client accepted");

                //create a new multi-server-thread object to handle new client
                //pass it the socket returned from the accept and start the thread
                new ServerThreads(clientSocket).start();


                //carry on listening for new connections forever

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("IO error " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        try{
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }


 }
}
```

Server Threads:

```
package com.degree.abbylaura.demothree.Server;

import com.degree.abbylaura.demothree.Server.ServerRequests;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerThreads extends Thread{

  private Socket clientSocket;

  public ServerThreads(Socket clientSocket){
    super();
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
  }

  public void run(){

    try {
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        PrintWriter outToClient =
                new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);


        Boolean communicating = true;
        String response = null;

        String myresponse = "FIRST TO CLIENT"; //debugging


        while(communicating){

            outToClient.println("FIRST TO CLIENT");
            response = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println(myresponse + " : " + response);


            if(response.equals("FIRST TO SERVER")){
                myresponse = "SECOND TO CLIENT";
                outToClient.println("SECOND TO CLIENT");

            }else if(response.equals("SECOND TO SERVER")){
                myresponse = "SERVER ENDING COMMUNICATION";
                outToClient.println("SERVER ENDING COMMUNICATION");

            }else if(response.equals("CLIENT END")){
                communicating = false;
            }

        }

        clientSocket.close();
        return;



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();


    } finally {
        try{
            clientSocket.close();
        }

        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




  }
}
```

Client:

```
package com.degree.abbylaura.demothree.Client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client {

  public static void main(String args[]){
    String hostName = "localhost";
    int portNumber = 8888; //TO CHANGE

    ClientHandler handler = new ClientHandler();

    //create client socket
    Socket socket = null;
    BufferedReader inFromServer = null;
    PrintWriter outToServer = null;

    try{
        socket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
        System.out.println("socket created");

        inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        outToServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);


        Boolean communicating = true;
        String response = null;
        String myresponse = null;


        while(communicating){

            response = inFromServer.readLine();
            System.out.println(myresponse + " : " + response);


            if(response.equals("FIRST TO CLIENT")){
                myresponse = "FIRST TO SERVER";

                outToServer.println("FIRST TO SERVER");

            }else if(response.equals("SECOND TO CLIENT")){
                myresponse = "SECOND TO SERVER";

                outToServer.println("SECOND TO SERVER");

            }else if(response.equals("SERVER ENDING COMMUNICATION")){
                myresponse = "CLIENT END";

                outToServer.println("CLIENT END");
                communicating = false; //may or may not need this line in
            }


        }


    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) you can start by studying this example

https://github.com/schwiz/android-websocket-example

https://github.com/schwiz/websocket-server

(server side is language independent - as we use sockets here so could be a c or java implementation or any other)

2) and basically you need to be familiar with "android api" aspects like:

```
 a. Service class
   (to maintain communication with server/ do job outside main aka ui thread)
 + Binder class :) functionality
   (allowing Activity and Service  to communicate with each other) 
 + ServiceConnection class 
   (to bind from Activity to Service to use Binder*) 

 b. wakelocks
   (for above to hold / persist connection)

 c. Socket class 
    (to create connection with server and exchange data)
```

*binder is an android IPC mechanism similar to the socket one you trying to achieve (with linux kernel build in support) and is a preferred by google mostly for security reasons - if your service will be a local one you can skip a part about binder transactions :) and focus more on other aspects of service based approach.